# Perfmon .blg file specification / parsing library

Tags: binary, file-format, perfmon

Where can I find a detailed, low-level spec for the Perfmon binary .blg file format? Or even better, has anyone written a low level, open source library (preferably in C, but any language would do) for parsing .blg files?

Comment: I don't think you'll find this format, but on Windows, you can still open & read a log file with C, I think using the PDH library. Have you read this http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1299/pdh/pdh.aspx  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't help for looking at historical data, but if you have access to the systems running Perfmon, you may want to look at [Logman](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx). With Logman you can set performance counters AND specify the output format, that way you can just chose a format that is easy to parse. See the `-f` option:

`-f { bin | bincirc | csv | tsv | SQL } : Specifies the file format used for collecting performance counter and trace data. You can use binary, circular binary, comma and tab separated, or SQL database formats when collecting performance counters.`

As others have said if you also have historical records you need to parse you can use the [Relog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490958.aspx) utility to convert existing .blg files in to a more useful format.

Answer (score 8):

There's a tool called relog that can convert these files to csv or other formats.

http://blog.bennett-scharf.com/2008/12/17/converting-an-existing-perfmon-blg-file-to-csv/

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150623220325/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/adcman/archive/2006/05/15/598149.aspx)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123193607/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/granth/archive/2008/09/23/relogging-perfmon-binary-log-files-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: That's a dead link. Here's a working link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/relog

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to export the perfmon Data Collection Set as a template, and change the log file format in the XML - look for the LogFileFormat tag and change the value to the format of your preference

0 = CSV, 1 = TSV, 2 = SQL, 3 = the default binary format.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to incorporate PerfMon data into a SIEM, and found that getting perfmon to log to a SQL DB (and reading the data from a SQL view, from the SIEM agent) was the best way of doing this.

I can't say much about other products, but in LogRhythm SIEM, you need a "UDLA" (universal database log adapter) log source for it - and if you want to parse/contextualise the metadata, you'll need some parsing rules (ie regex) for what the query returns.

It's useful to see things like "if there's *x* number of logon errors, AND Avail MBytes is less than 100, THEN trigger alarm/AIEngine rule 'Insufficient Memory to Process Logons'".

That's a pretty lame example, but you get the idea.

You might also look at other things which have a potentially malicious explanation, and also a benign explanation.
For example - if you see a large amount of failed attempts to reset passwords, this might usually indicate some malicious behaviour - but not if you see the perfmon counters telling you that the Domain Controller has a total of less than 1,000 free system PTEs (admittedly unlikely on a 64-bit OS), or is seeing CPU usage of more than 95%. In which case, it's not necessarily a security issue, it's a load/capacity issue - or something is very wrong with your DC.